# Reporting Services Aggregate not working for parent-child relationships

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I have a parent-child attribute relationship in an Analysis services dimension, say `[Dim].[Child]` is a child of `[Dim].[Parent]` and I have a query, that returns the set

`UNION(
  [Dim].[Parent].Members * [Dim].[Child].Members,
  [Dim].[Parent].[ALL] * [Dim].[Child].Members
)`

on axis 1 and some output on axis 0. The query works fine when run in management studio.

Now I'm trying to make a chart in Reporting Services with `[Dim].[Child]` on the x axis and `Aggregate(some_output)` on the Y axis. I expect to see child members on the x axis with the output aggregated for all parents (which is just one in this case), i.e. the data taken from the line `{ [Dim].[Parent].[ALL], [Dim].[Child].&[TheChildID] }`. As stated above, the query does indeed return this line with the correct data.

However, the `Aggregate` function in this case returns NULL. This behaviour is always present when using parent-child attributes and putting the child on the X axis. The same also happends when putting the child in a tablix row and adding an aggregated output in a column. It seems like the Reporting Server is aware that the aggregation will be happening for only one member and refuses to do it.

If I make another identical query, just put in attributes which have a different relationship, e.g. `[Time].[Month]` and `[Time].[DayOfMonth]`, aggregation works fine, since this time the same day can belong to many months and data needs to be aggregated.

Now I have no idea why is this happening - does the Reporting Server acctually query the OLAP data source to figure out the relationship or what ? Or is there some magic in the query that returns the ALL rows, which I'm not aware of ? The only correlation for cases which work and which don't seems to be the relationship.

**EDIT:** some observations after playing around more: the report works if I remove the line `[Parent].Members * [Child].Members` from the query, forcing it to retrieve only `[Parent].ALL * [Child].&[ID]` rows. The chart now has data aggregated, but obviously, I don't have individual members anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of observations that I hope will help.

1. The aggregate function in reporting services requires a "scope" parameter...for example Aggregate(Fields!Child.value, "ParentGroup")
2. Your data provider must support this function. If it doesn't then "Nothing" is returned. See link below...

For more help/info check [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155830.aspx) function documentation.

Comment: The scope parameter is optional and Analysis services does support the Aggregate function.

Comment: If you don't specify the scope then it will use the current scope it is in. Are you sure of the current scope and that it is what you want?

Comment: I'm only doing groupping on the ChildID in the chart, I can't specify anything else in the scope parameter.